# Fill a Tree with Text in Java

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

I need to create a method in a class called Dictionary that recursively reads the contents of a txt file, line by line, in java, and then adds each line as a node to a tree. Here's a sample of the content of the file:

```
ourselves
out
over
own
same
shan't
she 
all
am
a
about
above
after
again
against
aren't 
should
shouldn't
so
some
such
than
that
that's
the
their
```

It goes on for over quadruple that length. I already have the Binary tree set up, and it includes these methods:

```
getKey() //returns the value of the current node
setKey() //sets the value of the current node
getLeftChild() //gets the value of the left child of the node inside the parentheses 
getRightChild() //does the same as the above, but with the right child
setLeftChild(BinaryTreeNode node) //sets the left child
setRightChild(BinaryTreeNode node) //sets the right child
```

In the end, the tree is just supposed to have the individual lines of text from the txt file as individual nodes within the tree. I've been having a lot of trouble with recursion and am Not sure how to get the program to read the contents of the file properly. I would really appreciate any suggestions or help.

If it helps, here's the broken, 1/4 completed method I have so far:

```
public Dictionary(String filePath) throws IOException{ // the file path in my system for
        //dictionary.txt
        //I read from this file and build my tree. 
        BufferedReader br = new 
                BufferedReader(new FileReader("Dictionary.txt"));


        String word; 

        if ((word = br.readLine()) == null)
            System.out.println("Your tree is empty.");
        while ((word = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //now I need to tell it to add word as a node. 

        }
        br.close();

    }
```

---EDIT---

There are no other requirements for how the tree is set up. Each individual line of text from the Dictionary.txt file simply has to be an individual node. That is, "ourselves" and "out" need to be separate nodes, et cetera.

Comment: Please tell us more the requirement (homework question) .. Does the tree (binary tree) need to be constructed in alphabetical order of the words, or just random order is fine?

Comment: Looks like a homework question. Also I'd suspect it has to be sorted....

Comment: I believe I can help you with this part of your question: "...Not sure how to get the program to read the contents of the file properly." Instead of using a `BufferedReader`, why not use the `Scanner` class like this: `Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Dictionary.txt"));`  Then set up your while loop like so: while(input.hasNextLine()) { word = input.nextLine(); // more code }`. Just make sure to throw the `FileNotFoundException` instead of IOException and also import `java.util.Scanner`, `java.io.File` and `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

Comment: If he has to use recursion to read the file, he can't use the scanner with a while loop, he has to make a recursive call to his reading function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a `Node` that can be constructed like this (you don't need the getter and setters right now):

```
 // the standard constructor to assign dummy values
 public Node(){
     this.key="";
     this.leftNode=null;
     this.rightNode=null;
 }

 // the constructor with parameters for both children
 public Node(String key, Node left, Node right){ 
      ...  // assign the paramteres
 }
```

First I would set up a method that actually reads *recursively* through the file:

```
 public Node readFile(BufferedReader reader){
     String word = reader.readLine();         
     if(word!=null){
         return new Node(word, readFile(reader), readFile(reader));            
     }else{
         return new Node() ;  // empty node or null?
     }      
 }
```

**EDIT**

then you can initialize your dictionary like this:

```
   private Node dictionaryTree;   // this is the tree within your dictionary class

   public Dictionary(String filePath) throws IOException{
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Dictionary.txt"));
         this.dictionaryTree = readFile(br);
         br.close();
   }
```

I am not 100% sure that this will actually work as you want it to, but it follows the recursition principle. After that the `root` is you complete tree and you can go through the `getLeftChild()` and `getRightChild()` methods to iterate your way through the tree.

Comment: How does this connect back to the Dictionary.txt file?

Comment: yea, I forgot: before you start creating your tree with `Node root = readFile(bufferedReader);` you should initialize your BufferedReader. The reader will be connected to the textfile and it will always know which line is next.

Comment: sorry I just realized I did call it `Node` instead of `BinaryTreeNode` as you did (maybe I was too lazy to write ;)